# Can I use punctuation in Stanford CoreNLP Named Entities?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to get Stanford Core NLP to recognise an identification code. The problem is the code has punctuation in it. e.g. `01.A01.01` which causes the input to be separated into three sentences.

The matching expression for this code would be `[0-9][0-9][.][a-z,A-Z][0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9]`. I've tried adding this into my `regexner.txt` file but it doesn't identify it (presumably because the tokens are across separate sentences?)

I've also tried to match it using a TokenRegex similar to the following (also without any success).

`/tell/ /me/ /about/ (?$refCode /[0-9][0-9]/ /./ /[a-z,A-Z][0-9][0-9]/ /./ /[0-9][0-9]/ )`

Some example uses...

> The user has resource 02.G36.63 reserved.
>
> Is 21.J83.02 available?

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Could you present some typical input text.  Is it necessary to split it into sentences?

Comment: hi @StanfordNLPHelp. I've added some sample usage to my question above. Ideally I'd like these to be parsed as a single sentence and the period (.) to not be treated as the end of the sentence. Even better is if I the code could be treated as a single token and identified as a Named Entity. However I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your sample input and replaced "\n" with " ", to create:

```
The user has resource 02.G36.63 reserved.  Is 21.J83.02 available?
```

I created this rules file (sample-rules.txt):

```
02.G36.63       ID_CODE    MISC    2
```

And I ran this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -regexner.mapping sample-rules.txt -ssplit.eolonly -tokenize.whitespace -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text
```

I got this output:

```
Sentence #1 (9 tokens):
The user has resource 02.G36.63 reserved.  Is 21.J83.02 available?
[Text=The CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=3 PartOfSpeech=DT Lemma=the NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=user CharacterOffsetBegin=4 CharacterOffsetEnd=8 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=user NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=has CharacterOffsetBegin=9 CharacterOffsetEnd=12 PartOfSpeech=VBZ Lemma=have NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=resource CharacterOffsetBegin=13 CharacterOffsetEnd=21 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=resource NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=02.G36.63 CharacterOffsetBegin=22 CharacterOffsetEnd=31 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=02.g36.63 NamedEntityTag=ID_CODE]
[Text=reserved. CharacterOffsetBegin=32 CharacterOffsetEnd=41 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=reserved. NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=Is CharacterOffsetBegin=43 CharacterOffsetEnd=45 PartOfSpeech=VBZ Lemma=be NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=21.J83.02 CharacterOffsetBegin=46 CharacterOffsetEnd=55 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=21.j83.02 NamedEntityTag=O]
[Text=available? CharacterOffsetBegin=56 CharacterOffsetEnd=66 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=available? NamedEntityTag=O]
```

This said to just tokenize on whitespace, so it stopped breaking on the periods.  Also it said to only split sentences on newline, so it is important in the input file to put the entire user request on one line.  You won't get sentences, but you can get a token stream and identify your product codes.

Now if you really want the full power of Stanford CoreNLP and you don't want to have these codes split, you could take the ambitious route and alter the tokenizer PTBLexer.flex file to include all of your id codes.

That file is here in the repo:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex

You'll have to Google around to find instructions on compiling the PTBLexer.flex file into PTBLexer.java.  This site should have the info you need:

http://www.jflex.de/

This would basically mean adding in your id codes and making a few slight edits, and then rebuilding PTBLexer.  Then with your custom tokenizer Stanford CoreNLP would treat your product codes like complete tokens and you could have normal sentence splitting if you want to do something like analyze the dependency structure of your user requests.

Comment: Thanks. This approach will work for me as the text I'm processing is simple one liners. They should never be more than a sentence anyway.

Comment: Do you know why making this change (i.e. adding -ssplit.eolonly -tokenize.whitespace) would stop some of the other functionality from working. I've notice two issues. 1) Things like "I'm" are no longer interpreted as "I am" and 2) ner identification has become a bit hit and miss (e.g. Australia identified as a LOCATION but France was no)?